# NSRangeException while changing uitableview data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, nsmutablearray, nsrange

I am both new here and in IOS programming, so please bear with my newbee questions for a while :]

Here is the situation of my application before my question:

I have a view in which i added 3 different subviews. (1-categories, 2-words and 3-rules)
Within the categories subview I have a table of categories. (reads and writes from a categories plist and array)

According to the selected category I am changing the table ingredients for words table in the words subview. This table keeps the words the user enters for a selected category. (reads and writes from an nsmutabledictionary whose keys are the category names from the categories table and whose values are arrays of strings which were pre-entered by me to the plist)

Now an example to make things clear:
my categories array has: Size, Color
my words array for Size category has 3 strings in it like so: "tiny" , "big", "huge"
my words array for Color category has 2 strings in it like so: "red", "blue"

First when i select "Size" category, i go and fetch words within that category and when i move from categories subview to words subview i see everything inside the "Size" category correctly in my uitableview. (it prints "tiny", "big" and "huge")

But when i go back to my categories subview and select "Color" this time and go back to words subview i get a crash.

Seems like it calls tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, and i get an NSRangeException as below:

```
[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds
```

Long story short, I want to know why the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is calling an index which is not there. Here is how inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath method looks like:

```
[self reinitializeWordsDictionary];
[self reinitializeWordsInSelectedCategoryArray];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
        reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [wordsInSelectedCategoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

Thanks in advance for the answers,

tiw

Comment: The interesting part is: what is in `wordsInSelectedCategoryArray` ? For examples, what does `[wordsInSelectedCategoryArray count]` yield ? So the `reinitializeWordsInSelectedCategoryArray` is of interest here, if it's not too long please edit your post and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me that the `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;`
 method of the `UITableView`'s data source is delivering wrong values. I would check that by setting a break point on this method and evaluate the returned values.

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to mark this answer as the correct one to improve your accepted answer score.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone reading this has NSRangeExceptions not thrown by cellForRowAtIndexPath, check to ensure your UITableView isn't wrongly set to "static cells" content.

Answer (score 0):

What are you giving back in

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

?